# Commercially available spyware not getting detected

Tags: monitoring, spyware

I guess everyone here knows those commercially available stealth PC monitoring software.

I'm surprised that those trojans are hardly detected by virus scanners.

All surveillance makers recommend in their FAQs one should add their program to the virus scanner's exception list. After some quick tests in various virtual machines, I was surprised that this is not necessary in most cases. Even the Avast pre-boot scan didn't find the virus.

11 / 60 virus total's scanners recognized the trojan. It was a free, public
trial version! No modifications! All 11 hits were "generic". One of those
malware programmers offers all surveillance methods you can think of, but
not keylogger. To avoid Antivirus detection.

What's the easiest way to find these malware?

Malwarebytes, for example, says they had proprietary methods that were
better than the other scanners, but at least in the affected, running
Windows, they didn't find more of those viruses.

Comment: You'll generally have to write your own spyware if you want it to go undetected (and 11 out of 60 is a really bad score for malware, meaning it's not very stealthy at all). "Commercial spyware" is usually either a scam or horribly overpriced.

Comment: @forest I think OP is asking the opposite question - these programs are freely available, so why isn't the hit rate 100%?

Comment: Primarily because it is detected using heuristics, which each vendor may implement differently. But even for well-known malware, the hit rate is unlikely to ever be 100%. AV is crappy in general.

Comment: The problem is that they are not *malware* but *PUPs* (potentially unwanted programs). You, if you are not expecting them, might consider them malware, but their functions may be no different from any number of remote admin programs. That's the problem.